# docx4j html to pdf word-break issue

Tags: docx4j

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        p {
            word-break: break-all;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="width: 500px">
<p>
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
</body>
</html>
```

the html code is looks this ↑

[This is the effect of html in the browser [Click to view]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcYEa.png)

```
    @Test
    void contextLoads() throws Docx4JException, FileNotFoundException, MalformedURLException {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\zx\\Desktop\\data2.html");
        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
        XHTMLImporterImpl XHTMLImporter = new XHTMLImporterImpl(wordMLPackage);
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(XHTMLImporter.convert(file.toURI().toURL()));
        Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\zx\\Desktop\\3.pdf"));
    }
```

the java code is looks this ↑

[This is the effect of pdf in the browser [Click to view]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueJue.png)

I want him to install the CSS style as shown in the following figure, and return the line

Answer (score 0):

The html importer that comes with docx4j can't handle a separated css file.

The styles should be inline in the html tags for being considered, in a style property.

And for inserting a break line, and move to the next line, in pdf it should be another text box, therefor you have to create a paragraph for each line you want, by measuring how many characters you can place in a single line.